# Vue v-if not hiding mobile header

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, header

I have this project where I try to add a mobile view menu. This menu is displayed by clicked a button. The button I have created switches a boolean on and off. But when the value of the boolean changes the v:if on the menu doesn't hide it. It keeps on showing.

This is my menu item inside the template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div> ... main menu ... </div>

    <div :v-if="menuOpened" class="bg-purple-primary h-10 z-20">
       <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Header',
  data () {
    return {
      menuOpened: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switchMenuState () {
      this.menuOpened = !this.menuOpened
      console.log(this.menuOpened)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: prefix `:` is not required in `v-if` directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need that colon before v-if directive

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="switchMenuState()">Switch</button>

    <div v-if="menuOpened" class="bg-purple-primary h-10 z-20">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data() {
    return {
      menuOpened: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    switchMenuState() {
      this.menuOpened = !this.menuOpened;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```